# Method to solve $xx'-x=f(t)$

Tags: calculus, reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to resolve this differential equation:

$xx'-x=f(t)$

any suggestions (or any online texts on similar differential equation) please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an ['Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form'](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0124.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! And is this Abel equation? $xx'-g(t)x=f(t)$

Comment: @Mark: More exactly this is a ['special case of the Abel differential equation of the second kind'](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0125.pdf) while the ['Abel differential equation of the second kind'](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0126.pdf) incorporates a x^2 term.

Comment: Although the recognition of EqWorld is quite well, it still behaves outdated about Abel differential equation of the second kind, since the article http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2 has been issued.

Answer (score 0):

Although the recognition of EqWorld is quite well, it still behaves outdated about Abel equation of the second kind.

The following information is really updated indeed:

$xx'-x=f(t)$ itself belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf