Solve a first-order ODE by quadrature
While working on some problems in nonlinear waves, I stumbled on a simple equation that I would really like to solve
$$
yy'+cy=f(x),
$$
where $c$ is a real constant.
I can solve specific examples of $f$. For example, if $f(x)=x$, then the substitution $y(x)=xv(x)$ gives a separable equation for $v$. Would anyone have a general procedure for reducing that equation to a quadrature? It just seems so simple.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167756/method-to-solve-xx-x-ft?noredirect=1.

Yikes, nice catch @Gonçalo!

I agree with @A rural reader, thank you @Gonçalo.

Thanks to @Gonçalo, the answers for that question are exactly what I needed.
